# Replicate Gnome UI display scaling in i3

Tags: x11, gnome, xrandr, i3

I'm using i3 with some `xrandr` functions to set up my displays.

I'm on a Dell laptop with 4K OLED screen.

When I log into Gnome, by default its displaying scaling is set to 200% and everything is perfect. Applications are the correct size and the image quality is immaculate.

In i3, using `xrandr`, I can't get the same combination of size and quality. When I set the `scale` property, the image immediately blurs regardless of the scale I use (`0.9x0.9`, `0.5x0.5` etc). I've tried messing about with the `dpi` property too, but I notice little effect from this.

If I reduce the resolution to 2K, this is my best option - but it just isn't as good as the Gnome 4K resolution with 200% scaling. It's slightly too small and its image quality is slightly worse.

Is there a way I can replicate the Gnome Display Manager's 200% scaling with a 4K resolution?